# How to use Curl to send parameters and values?

Tags: html, linux, curl, parameters

i am trying to send a curl request to a webpage using GET to send parameters with their values. it works for the first two, but the last one "a-listibg-pro" keeps giving  me trouble because of the hyphen i assume. please help

```
 curl -X GET <url>?"type"="fruit"&"number"="two hundred and one"&"a-listing-pro"="yes but conditional"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hypens are URL safe, so that should not be the problem.

Mind, that spaces and other special chars need to be URL encoded before used in a query string.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Spaces are usually encoded with `%20` or `+`, so your string can be used as

```
curl "https://example.com/?type=fruit&number=two%20hundred%20and%20one&a-listing-pro=yes%20but%20conditional"
```

(curl defaults to `GET` so no need for `-x`)

Comment: i had no idea! i learned something new from you, thank you so much !!! however it still won't work, i get something like:  [1] 6315 [2] 6316 bash: a-listing-pro=yes%20but%20conditional : command not found

Comment: You need to escape the whole URL with `" "` to prevent bash from trying to interpret the string. I'll update my answer.

Comment: omg it just worked !!!! i am forever grateful to you ! thank you for helping and for teaching me this valuable info! bless youuuu